# undocumented `updateDimensions` function of Vuetify

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm using Vue2 and Vuetify 2. I can reference a `v-menu` like

`<v-menu ref="aMenu"> </v-menu>` I see this reference has a function named `updateDimensions` but I don't see any documentation. Is it a Vuetify function or Vue function or even DOM function? How should it be used? Is it async? ...

Comment: it's an internal function.  there are hundreds of functions, pieces of state, and event handlers used internally across all the vuetify components that provide the functionality you see when using the components.  they're not meant for you to use as an end user.  anything meant to be exposed to the user is documented in the API docs.

Comment: but we use it, it is handy :)